# Firebase - Subdomain for each client

Tags: firebase, multi-tenant, wildcard-subdomain

Using firebase hosting is it possible to give each client their own subdomain on registration?

*For example;*

```
clientA.startup.com
clientB.startup.com
```

I could not find an API for domains and see no wildcard support in the docs.

Thanks,
Lewis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently a supported use case of Firebase Hosting. We are examining support for wildcard domains in the future, but it's not in the near-term roadmap. We may eventually open an API for adding domains, but if we did it would not be intended to be used for a massively-multi-tenant use case.

Comment: I would also like to request this feature! It's the only reason I don't use firebase hosting.

Comment: where's the sad-face emoji?  Was all set to use firebase hosting, but this is a no-go for me.