# Dynamically create subdomain for each client?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I know many ppl asked this question before. But they are answer years ago. Now it's 2020. Not sure if Firebase supports subdomain for each client now. Can anyone can give an update?

Link to the old question:
[Firebase - Subdomain for each client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008455/firebase-subdomain-for-each-client)

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard domains (e.g. `*.mydomain.com`) are not yet supported by Firebase Hosting, and due to limitations of our Certificate Authority (Let's Encrypt), there are relatively low limits on the number of subdomains of a given domain that can have certificates minted in a given time period.

For now, the answer remains that this is not a use case that is supported well on Firebase Hosting, and we don't recommend using Firebase Hosting for massively multi-tenant custom domains at this time.

Comment: What a sad news! Will the Cloud DNS help in this case? I mean whenever a new user signs up, I call Cloud DNS API to add a A record and point it to the apex address?

Comment: Is there an update to this in 2022?

Comment: Firebase Hosting still does not support wildcard domains as of Sep 2022.